# Got in bulk collect PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER

Tags: arrays, oracle, collections, numbers, ora-00932

I created types

```
create or replace type rec_int_g as object( i integer);
create or replace type typ_int_g is table of rec_int_g;
```

And a function

```
create function table_randset 
 return pls_integer is
  
 int_array typ_int_g := typ_int_g();


begin
  
select product_id bulk collect into int_array

  from product;

return randset(int_array);
end;
```

But got in select
PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER
error. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what the error says, you are passing numbers to the collection, when it is expecting a user-defined type. That's because your query is returning a number, not an object. So instead of:

```
select product_id bulk collect into int_array from product;
```

do:

```
select rec_int_g(product_id) bulk collect into int_array from product;
```

You also don't need to initialise the collection before a bulk-collect into it, you can simplify that to:

```
int_array typ_int_g;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vlcmpu_E) with anonymous block rather than function.

---

That's assuming you need an object type at all; presumably that's what `randset()` is expecting, but it looks like you could have defined `typ_int_g` as `table of integer` or `table of number`, perhaps.

> I dont know how get aggregates from plain array (how to address to column name? which column name?)

There is a `column_value` pseudo-column name for collections. So you can do:

```
select count(column_value), min(column_value), max(column_value)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/frFedswY)

Comment: Thanx a lot, it works. I cant use plain array of integers because of using aggregates further fot this collection like this select count(i), min(i), max(i) into cnt, lwm, hwm from table(int_array); and I dont know how get aggregates from plain array (how to address to column name? which column name?)

Comment: @Dmytro - you can use `column_value` (as I only just noticed William already mentioned too). I've added an example and fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You `int_array` isn't an array of integers, it's an array of `rec_int_g` objects, so you have to construct an `rec_int_g` for each row you fetch (I've used `user_objects` for a demo as I don't have your tables):

```
create or replace type rec_int_g as object( i integer);
create or replace type typ_int_g is table of rec_int_g;
```

```
declare
    int_array typ_int_g := typ_int_g();
begin
    select rec_int_g(o.object_id) as product_id bulk collect into int_array
    from   user_objects o;
end;
```

This would be simpler if `int_array` was a plain array of integers. Are you sure you need objects here?

Also the naming is a bit confusing. `rec_` means an object type (not a record), and `type_` means a collection type?

Comment: Thanx a lot, it works.  I cant use plain array of integers because of using aggregates further fot this collection like this 
  select count(i), min(i), max(i) into cnt, lwm, hwm 
    from table(int_array);  and I dont know how get aggregates from plain array (how to address to column name? which column name?)

Comment: It's `column_value` in SQL.

Comment: As I see plain array of integers ten times faster than object. Its cool